# quick into 'Function Analysis', ‘Measure Theory’

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

Can someone suggests some quick introduction document?

Comment: Terence Tao has a free text on his website: http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/measure-book1.pdf

Comment: For measure theory I suggest first chapter of Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis (the title is misleading) and for Functional Analysis Kaballo, Functional Analysis. Both are pretty brief but investigate the key concepts. *(Not comprehensive!)*

Answer (score 2):

From my own experience, I prefer the book Analysis by Lieb and Loss. They spend two chapters on real analysis and Lp space, and then move to some more interesting areas like rearrangement inequalities, Fourier analysis and Sobolev space. That is, you can learn the importance of several "big theorems" through great examples in the following chapters, and this will in turn help you think more deeply on the previous chapters.

While you have some problems, you can surely refer to some standard textbook.